# How to exclude some files and directories from git pull requests

Tags: git, github

This is a beginner question about how to properly manage a project with git.

I'm building a static website based on one available in a git repo, but with my own content and style customizations. So I start with the following steps:

1. Clone the project with `git clone url-to-source-repo my-project && cd my-project`
2. Since my-project starts here and I'll never make a merge request with the source repo, I don't need the full commit history of the source project, so I `rm -rf .git` then `git init`
3. I also want my-project to live on github, so I create a repo there and then `git remote add origin my-project-on-github-url.git`
4. In this project, there are many files and directories that I *won't* change, and which I want to benefit from upstream improvements in the future, so I `git remote add upstream url-to-source-repo`
5. There are also some files and directories that I *will* change and need tracked by git, such as `README.md` and `content/`, but which I don't want overwritten when pulling upstream updates from the source repo

The first issue is that `git pull upstream master` fails with the error `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. Using `--allow-unrelated-histories` successfully merges them, but adds the full commit history of the source repo and overwrites my modified files, so it seems it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Two questions:

1. Is it necessary to include the full commit history of the source project in my project if I want to be able to pull upstream changes from the source in the future?
2. How can I prevent some files and directories from being overwritten when pulling upstream updates, as described above in #5?

Comment: 2 is easy: work on a branch. As for 1, your entire way of getting started (full clone and then rip out the repo and try to reconnect with the same remote) seems counterproductive. If you didn't want the whole history, you should have shallow-cloned and stopped.

Comment: @matt I didn't know about shallow cloning - thank you for this tip!